# How to connect to the local google cloud Datastore db?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've GAE application which creates some data in the Google Cloud Datastore and stores some binary files into the Google Cloud Storage - let's call the application **WebApp**.
Now I have a different application running on the Google compute engine. Let's call the application **ComputeApp**.

The **ComputeApp** is a backend process which is processing data created by the **WebApp**. I asked here [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502396/communication-with-datastore-and-cloud-storage-from-google-compute-engine-in-jav) previously which API can I use to communicate with Datastore from the **ComputeApp**. As suggested by @proppy, I implemented the **Datastore** communication using of the [Google Cloud Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/datastore/).

Everything works fine as far as I'm communicating with the Datastore in the Google cloud. I'm using the service account authentication.

Now I need to run my ComputeApp locally, on my development PC so I'll take data created by my local **WebApp** and stored into the local debug Datastore. I need it because I want to have a testing environment so I can debug may GAE app locally.

How should I modify my **ComputeApp** code to force it to **connect to my local debug Datastore** instead of connect to the Google cloud?

I googled a lot and didn't find any advice nor example. Only possible way I found that I should rewrite my code completely and use a different API to do that. Such is Datastore Remote API.
Is this really only way? Should I really rewrite whole ComputeApp to connect to the **local** DB?
Really?

I hope that I just overlooked something important and It's not true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Datastore has a local development server that you can use: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver

You can create and start the local datastore using the gcd tool which is linked to in the doc above.

If you use `DatastoreHelper.getDatastoreFromEnv();` to build your Datastore, you can tell it to connect to your local database by exporting the env variable `DATASTORE_HOST`:

```
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: @Fipil Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Not yet @Ralf. Only possible way I found is to implement my own WriteToStorage and ReadFromStorage method to my WebApp and call it when I want to communicate with the local STORAGE.

Comment: I removed all references about the Storage and I'll create another question. So this question is only related to the Datastore.