# How to write to local App Engine datastore with PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

**What is the best way to develop locally in PHP and the Google datastore?**

The [dev_appserver.py docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server) say I can view local datastore entities, but there is no documentation on how to connect/write to this local datastore using PHP.

I can write to the local datastore ***emulator*** using:

```
// Start emulator: gcloud beta emulators datastore start --data-dir=_datastore
// Pointing this to dev_appserver's 'API server' doesn't work.
putenv('DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=http://localhost:8081');
$datastore = $cloud->datastore();
```

But these entities do not show up in dev_appserver.py's local admin server at http://localhost:8000/datastore.

Even setting the dev_appserver's `--datastore_path` to be equal to the emulator's   `--data-dir` does nothing.

Why are the datastore emulator and dev_appserver.py's datastore different? They share the same name and the docs refer to them interchangeably. This is frustrating.

Is this the correct way to do local datastore development? Is there a way to write to the local datastore and have the entities show up in the admin server viewer?

Comment: I use PHP-GDS (disclaimer: I am the author) and it will write to the built-in data store which you can access through the local admin interface. https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Datastore Emulator and dev_appserver.py have different underlying storage.
So the entities on datastore emulator cannot be shown in the admin server viewer.

see:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/21
- [Connecting to AppEngine datastore in development via Cloud Datastore API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864925/connecting-to-appengine-datastore-in-development-via-cloud-datastore-api)

There are maybe two way to connect to local datasotre (I'm not tried with php):

1. Use [appengine-php-sdk for standard enviroment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk), start development server by dev_appserver.py, and view datastore from admin server viewer.
2. Use [google/cloud library for php](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/), and set `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` env variable.

Unfortunately there isn't viewer for emulator, so I'm developing cli tool to check datastore entities by GQL: https://github.com/nshmura/dsio

Answer (score 0):

have u tried passing the environment variables to the php executable *before* including the libraries?

maybe try this:

```
#/bin/sh
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=http://localhost:8081
dev_appserver.py ...
```