# How to connect to the local google cloud Storage from standalone java application (not from a GAE web-app)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've GAE application which creates some data in the Google Cloud Datastore and stores some binary files into the Google Cloud Storage - let's call the application **WebApp**.
Now I have a different application running on the Google compute engine. Let's call the application **ComputeApp**.

The **ComputeApp** is a backend process which is processing data created by the **WebApp**. I asked here [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502396/communication-with-datastore-and-cloud-storage-from-google-compute-engine-in-jav) previously which API can I use to communicate with Storage from the **ComputeApp**. I implemented the **Storage** communication using of the [Google Cloud Storage JSON API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/api-lib/java).

Everything works fine as far as I'm communicating with the Storage in the Google cloud. I'm using the service account authentication.

Now I need to run my ComputeApp locally, in my development PC so I'll take data created by my local **WebApp** and stored into the local debug Storage. I need it because I want to have a testing environment so I can debug may app locally. 
My WebApp running locally stores binary data to the local Datastore. I can see it through the local admin console: (localhost:8080/_ah/admin). There is list of entities **GsFileInfo** and a list of the __ah_FakeCloudStorage... entities, representing my **storage** data.

How should I modify my **ComputeApp** code to force it to **connect to my local debug Storage** and access these binary data stored locally instead of connect to the Google cloud?

Comment: ever figure this out or found a working example?

Comment: Unfortunately not. At the end I made what I needed different way.

Comment: i was able to figure it out..i will post an answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

Create account in Google Project Console, and Service account credentials

Initialize:

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "your-webapp";
      private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

       GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
              if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
                credential = credential.createScoped(StorageScopes.all());
              }
              HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
              storageService = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                  .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();



   InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(contentType, inputStream);


    StorageObject objectMetadata = null;
      objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
          .setName(name)
          .setMetadata(ImmutableMap.of("date", new Date().toString()))
          .setAcl(ImmutableList.of(
             new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allUsers").setRole("READER")

              ))
          .setContentDisposition("attachment");


    Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storageService.objects().insert("staging.your-app.appspot.com", objectMetadata,
        mediaContent);


    // For small files, you may wish to call setDirectUploadEnabled(true), to
    // reduce the number of HTTP requests made to the server.
    if (mediaContent.getLength() > 0 && mediaContent.getLength() <= 2 * 1000 * 1000 /* 2MB */) {
      insertObject.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
    }

    insertObject.execute();
```